# can't install python3 on BeagleBoneBlack (revC)

Tags: python-3.x, beagleboneblack, apt-get

The BeagleBoneBlack revC comes with Python2 installed. But we need to run Python3.

However, trying to install python3 with apt-get fails. it seems to try to install version 3.2 which does not exist on the download site (see http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/ )

```
root@beaglebone:~# sudo apt-get install python3 -V
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
   python3-minimal (3.2.3-6)
   python3.2 (3.2.3-7+deb7u1)
   python3.2-minimal (3.2.3-7+deb7u1)
Suggested packages:
   python3-doc (3.2.3-6)
   python3-tk (3.2.3-1)
   python3.2-doc (3.2.3-7+deb7u1)
   binfmt-support (2.0.12)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   python3 (3.2.3-6)
   python3-minimal (3.2.3-6)
   python3.2 (3.2.3-7+deb7u1)
   python3.2-minimal (3.2.3-7+deb7u1)
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 240 not upgraded.
Need to get 4246 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  python3.2-minimal python3.2 python3-minimal python3
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main python3.2-minimal armhf 3.2.3-7+deb7u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.0.204 80]
Err http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main python3.2 armhf 3.2.3-7+deb7u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.0.204 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main python3-minimal all 3.2.3-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main python3 all 3.2.3-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/python3.2/python3.2-minimal_3.2.3-7+deb7u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.0.204 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/p/python3.2/python3.2_3.2.3-7+deb7u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.0.204 80]
Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-minimal_3.2.3-6_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3_3.2.3-6_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

When trying to specify a version, it fails as well:

```
root@beaglebone:~# sudo apt-get install python3=3.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '3.4' for 'python3' was not found
```

Any advice?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest getting an updated version of the images they provide. I know that python3 comes preinstalled on their Buster versioning of the images.

https://beagleboard.org/latest-images

Comment: I strongly second this. Install an up to date Debian Buster imaage. Debian Wheezy has been out of even LontTermSupport since 2018!

Answer (score 1):

that's right. wheezy is old, no point wasting time on it. upgrading the debian image to the latest solved it easily. thanks!